# Number of mean and variance possible for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, means

Let $X ∼ N(μ, σ^2)$. Find the values of μ and $σ^2$ such that $P\left(|X| < 2\right) = \frac{1}{2}$

Are the values of μ and $σ^2$ unique? Prove or disprove it.

I am able to find reach the equation $F_x(2) < \frac{3}{4}$. But I am stuck after that. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We define the standard normal variate, $Z =\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. We then have, $$P(|X|<2) = P(-2<X<2) = P(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma})$$ $$=P(0<Z<\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma})+P(0<Z<\frac{2+\mu}{\sigma})=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now just look at the statistical tables.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $2P(0<Z<\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma}) - 1 =\frac{1}{2}$ ? Or rather just $2P(Z<\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma}) - 1 =\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I guess there is a tiny mistake: You could write $$P\Big(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)=F_Z\Big(\frac{2-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)-F_Z\Big(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)$$ Note that the lower bound is not the negative of the upper bound!

Comment: Won't it be $F_Z(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma})$ = $1 - F_Z(\frac{2+\mu}{\sigma})$ for the second part of the equation? I guess we can't just take the negative sign out like you have done.

Comment: @Dross Yes you can write $F_Z(\frac{-2-\mu}{\sigma})=1-F_Z(\frac{2+\mu}{\sigma})$

Comment: All this seems like brute-force to me. A neater solution should exist...